# Android app crashes when it reaches the line "ArrayList<Player> players= fs.getScores();" and I cant figure it out

Tags: java, android, onclick, nullpointerexception, onclicklistener

I have been working on a game for Android and I want to put highscores in. I think that this code should be working and cannot see why it isn't. I have got it set so that when the menu button is pressed a dialog box opens for the user to enter their name. This works but then when you press ok, the app crashes. The line it crashes on is `ArrayList<Player> players= fs.getScores();`

Here is the code for the activity class which is where it crashes:

```
package com.example.game;
import java.util.Collections;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

public class MyGame extends Activity {

    GameView gv;
    private final int DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY = 1;
    Filestore fs;
    private String GAME_KEY= "game_key";
    private Bundle sis;
    TextView hscores;
    String name = "";



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        gv = new GameView(this);
        setContentView(gv);
    gv.setStarted(true);
}


@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent msg) {
    if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT)
        gv.setSpriteState(2);
    if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT)
        gv.setSpriteState(1);
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU)
        showDialog(DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu); 
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_game, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
    // Handle item selection
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.new_game:
            gv = new GameView(this);
            gv.setStarted(true);
            setContentView(gv);
            return true;
        case R.id.save:
            showDialog(DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY);
            return true;
        case R.id.quit:
            finish();
            return true;
        case R.id.highscores:
            setContentView(R.layout.highscores);
            hscores = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myhighscores);
            ArrayList<Player> players= fs.getScores();
            if(!(players==null))
            {
                Collections.sort(players);
                String s=String.format("%15s%15s","NAME","SCORE\n");
                for(Player p:players)
                {
                    s+=String.format("%15s%15s",p.getName(),
                                    p.getScore()+"\n");
                }
                hscores.setText(s);
            }
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY:
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(this);
        final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.save, null);
        final EditText t = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.save_edit);
        name = t.toString();
        return new AlertDialog.Builder(MyGame.this)
                .setIcon(R.drawable.alert_dialog_icon)
                .setTitle(R.string.alert_dialog_save_title)
                .setView(textEntryView)
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.alert_dialog_ok,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {
                                Player p= new Player(t.getText().toString(),gv.getTime());
                                ArrayList<Player> players= fs.getScores();
                                if(players==null)
                                    players= new ArrayList<Player>();
                                players.add(p);
                                fs.saveScores(players);
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.alert_dialog_cancel,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int whichButton) {

                            }
                        }).create();
    }
    return null;
}

public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
        int whichButton) {
    Player p= new Player(name,gv.getTime());
    ArrayList<Player> players= fs.getScores();
    if(players==null)
            players= new ArrayList<Player>();
    players.add(p);
    fs.saveScores(players);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putBundle(GAME_KEY, gv.saveState());
    sis=outState;
}

}
```

And here is the logcat:

```
07-08 20:56:24.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1649): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-08 20:56:24.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1649): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-08 20:56:24.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1649):     at com.example.game.MyGame$1.onClick(MyGame.java:117)
07-08 20:56:24.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1649):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:159)
07-08 20:56:24.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1649):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-08 20:56:24.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1649):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-08 20:56:24.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1649):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
07-08 20:56:24.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1649):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-08 20:56:24.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1649):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-08 20:56:24.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1649):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
07-08 20:56:24.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1649):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
07-08 20:56:24.799: E/AndroidRuntime(1649):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I have tried to include everything I could think of but I am new to this. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you mark line 117 in your code please?

Comment: `fs` is null.  You never initialize it anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

```
ArrayList<Player> players= fs.getScores();
```

It seems `fs` is pointing to `null` and resulting in `NullPointerException`.

In your code you are no where pointing `fs` to valid instance/object.

Comment: fs is an instance of filestore which is another class

Comment: @Glenn Coogan: fs is reference and it should be pointed to filestore instance, which is not in your code.

Comment: @GlennCoogan: In your onCreate method, you need to instantiate and assign it.

Comment: Okay. I know I probably sound really nooby but how would I write this in code?

Comment: FileStore class is not in your question, so I can't guarantee, but usual syntax would be: fs = new FileStore();

Answer (score 0):

The field `fs` (the file store) is not initialized. You need to create (or get) an instance first, maybe like you initialize the `GameView` in your `onCreate` method.